# ERROR: cache lookup failed for procedure 0 on update

Tags: postgresql, search-path

I have the following table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE idempiere.tbl_test
(
  val numeric(10,0)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE idempiere.tbl_test
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

when I try to run the following sql script on it, it returns an error:

```
update tbl_test set val=val+10;
```

error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  cache lookup failed for procedure 0
```

I tested it with another schema in the same database and it worked. My problem is that this schema has many tables and functions.
I created a new schema and tested with my test table, but after restoring dump file
it's not working again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Insufficient information. Are there triggers on this table? Show `\dt+ tbl_test`.

Comment: Which version of Postgresql are you using? Works fine under 9.3 64bit Windows... although you obviously have to write update idempiere.tbl_test...

Comment: 1.there are no triggers on this table(its a new table i just created after restoring dumpfile). 2.it works fine with a clean db, but after restoring dumpfile its not working.

Comment: What do you get for `SHOW search_path;` in the *same session*? Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

Comment: i get this : idempiere, "$user", public